# MySQL - Unable to set table-specific privilages

Tags: mysql

I want to give one of my users access to a few tables only, however when I execute the following query:

> GRANT SELECT (credits_features_csgo, steam_code, credits_csgo, userid,
>        credits_forum, credits_features_tf2, credits_tf2, credits_css, credits_features),
>   INSERT (credits_features_csgo, steam_code, credits_csgo, userid, credits_forum,
>        credits_features_tf2, credits_tf2, credits_css, credits_features), 
>   UPDATE (credits_features_csgo, steam_code, credits_csgo, userid, credits_forum,
>        credits_features_tf2, credits_tf2, credits_css, credits_features),
>   CREATE,
>   REFERENCES (credits_features_csgo, steam_code, credits_csgo, userid, credits_forum,
>        credits_features_tf2, credits_css, credits_features),
>   ALTER
>   ON `bob_forum`.`vb_user`
>   TO 'bob_store'@'localhost';

It executes successfully, however, when I go to check the user's privileges, it is only granted usage. The Database is MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct. If there were no errors, then all privileges are granted.

Try to check privileges using this query -

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'bob_store'@'localhost';
```